# typescript import { RegExp }

Tags: typescript

I want to use RegExp from typescript but in Visual Studio Code is marked as an error.

```
            import { RegExp } from "RegularExpressions/Regex"; // module not found.
            export class BotAnswerRegex {
                createRegex(){
                    var regex = new RegExp('hi');
                    // regex.isMatch is marked as an error
                    var result = regex.isMatch('hi, i am peter');
                }
            }
```

I am following the doc.
http://electricessence.github.io/TypeScript.NET/documentation/classes/_source_system_text_regularexpressions_.regex.html

Update:
Fix variable declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use this libarary your code should be like this:

```
import RegExp from "typescript-dotnet-commonjs/System/Text/RegularExpressions";
// ...
let regex = new RegExp('hi');
let result = regex.isMatch('hi, i am peter');
// ...
console.log(result);
// ...
```

**UPDATE**

Note that your code is not correct, you are declaring a local var:

```
var regex = new RegExp('hi');
```

And you are trying to access this var using `this`:

```
... this.regex.isMatch('hi, i am peter');
```

Comment: Still the error `[ts] Cannot find module 'typescript-dotnet-commonjs/System/Text/RegularExpressions'.
`

Comment: How do you installed the `typescript-dotnet-commonjs` module? try to use `npm install typescript-dotnet-commonjs`

Comment: Do I need to do npm install? It's not working for me